# Unable to make .zhistory a symbolic link

Tags: zsh, command-history, git

Every time I try to make my Zsh history file (`.zhistory` file) a symbolic link to a file (previously existing `.zhistory` file) that lives in another folder, Zsh deletes the symbolic link and makes it a regular file.

I have tried creating the symbolic link in Bash and then switching back to Zsh, but Zsh will still always remove the link and copy the file instead.

Why is this? How can I have my `.zshistory` file live somewhere else ? (in my case a git repository not located in the home directory)

Comment: Probably `zsh` is recreating the file each time.

Comment: @vonbrand It actually **copies** the file using the symlink, instead of creating an empty one from scratch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to not use links at all. The location of the `zsh` history file is determined by the value of `$HISTFILE`. So, to have that backed up, change it from the default value to a file in the watched directory. Add this line to your `.zshrc`:

```
HISTFILE=~/foo/.zhistory
```

Now, copy the existing file over to the new location and any new shell you open should use the new file for saving the history.